# How to format and output table and constant data in a Scala Dateframe as JSON objects

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I was wondering, given a table and constant data and using Scala, how would we format the data to output as JSON objects accordingly as below:

| First Name | Last Name | Ticket Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Smith | Alpha |
| Bob | Smith | Alpha |
| Bob | Smith | Beta |
| Bob | Smith | Zeta |
| Bob | Apple | Alpha |

With the given data set, I want to group it based on First Name and Last Name format it so that it tracks the tickets for each of the names. The tickets will have constant variables that we know. This is a little bit confusing so here's what the expected output looks like:

```
    {
        "Total Number of Tickets": 4
        "First Name": "Bob"
        "Last Name": "Smith"
        "Tickets": [{
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 123,
                     "Name": "Alpha" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 100,
                     "Object": "Vacation Package"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 2
        }, {
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 234,
                     "Name": "Beta" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 200,
                     "Object": "Car"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 1
        }, {
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 345,
                     "Name": "Zeta" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 300,
                     "Object": "Home"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 1
        }]
    }
    {
        "Total Number of Tickets": 1
        "First Name": "Bob"
        "Last Name": "Apple"
        "Tickets": [{
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 123,
                     "Name": "Alpha" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 100,
                     "Object": "Vacation Package"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 1
        }, {
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 234,
                     "Name": "Beta" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 200,
                     "Object": "Car"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 0
        }, {
             "Ticket Specifications" {
                 "Ticket Unique Identifiers": {
                     "Barcode": 345,
                     "Name": "Zeta" 
                 },
                 "Ticket Prizes": {
                     "Cash": 300,
                     "Object": "Home"
                 }    
             },
             "numberOfThisTicket": 0
        }]
    }
```

As you can see, we discovered two groups based on the criteria (Bob Smith and Bob Apple) so we want to format, based on the given data, and output it as it appears above. Since we had two groups, notice that there's two JSON objects ouputted into the file. You can see the constant data (Ticket Unique Identifiers and Ticket Prizes) that isn't included in the data set but we will know them and they are the same no matter what

How would we, given the table and knowledge of the constant data and using Scala and Scala Dataframes, format and output it as seen above?

Update:

Constant data table,

| Ticket Name | Ticket Barcode | Ticket Cash | Ticket Object |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 123 | 100 | Vacation Package |
| Beta | 234 | 200 | Car |
| Zeta | 345 | 300 | Home |

Comment: Could you please add another sample dataframes which has values of Barcode, Object, cash- which are not present in the sample data which you provided?

Comment: Hi Mohana, thanks for your reply. I updated to provide a constant data table. I do want to note that the table can be organized in any shape or form, if you find reorganizing the table to be helpful in the solution let me know. The table is supposed to be arbitrary and something that is most likely created during the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By considering sample data which you provided, I tried to get JSON structure out of it by using joining, window, and aggregation functionalities. Output JSON is almost similar to what you are expecting, you may enhance the same code according to your usecase.

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  // Sample dataframes
  val df1 = List(
    ("Bob", "Smith", "Alpha"),
    ("Bob", "Smith", "Alpha"),
    ("Bob", "Smith", "Beta"),
    ("Bob", "Smith", "Zeta"),
    ("Bob", "Apple", "Alpha")).toDF("First Name", "Last Name", "Ticket Name")

  val df2 = List(
    ("Alpha", 123, 100, "Vacation Package"),
    ("Beta", 234, 200, "Car"),
    ("Zeta", 345, 300, "Home")
  ).toDF("Ticket Name", "Ticket Barcode", "Ticket Cash", "Ticket Object")

  val outDF = df1.join(df2, Seq("Ticket Name"))
    // To get count of each ticket per person
    .withColumn("numberOfThisTicket", count("Ticket Name").over(
      Window.partitionBy("First Name", "Last Name", "Ticket Name")))
    // To form nested structure required for JSON by grouping
    .groupBy("First Name", "Last Name")
    .agg(
      count("Ticket Name").as("Total Number of Tickets"),
      collect_set(
        struct(
          struct(
            struct(
              col("Ticket Barcode").as("Barcode"),
              col("Ticket Name").as("Name")
            )
              .as("Ticket Unique Identifiers"),
            struct(
              col("Ticket Cash").as("Cash"),
              col("Ticket Object").as("Object")
            )
              .as("Ticket Prizes")
          )
            .as("Ticket Specifications"), 'numberOfThisTicket)
      )
        .as("Tickets"))

  // To convert each struct type rows to JSON
  val jsonDF = outDF.toJSON

  // To form single/complete JSON row out of all json rows
  val jsonStringDF = jsonDF.groupBy(lit(1))
    .agg(collect_list("value").as("json"))
    .select('json.cast("string"))

  // Get single json row as string
  println(jsonStringDF.first.getString(0))
```